# using both of "collection" and "schema" attribute in autoform

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I have one "Ads" collection in mongoDB, and too many schema in following format:

```
AdsBaseSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  _parentId: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 200
  }
  description: {
    type: String,
    label: "Description",
    optional: true
  }
});
```

but they are different is some fields.

and I want to use them for insert autoform. like this:

```
{{> quickForm schema="AdsBaseSchema" id="insBaseAds" type="method" meteormethod="insBaseAds"}}
```

with this method:

```
insBaseAds: function(doc) {
    Ads.insert(doc);
    this.unblock();
}
```

**This approach works correctly! But this is my question:**

Its hard for me to use this approach for all of my schema! (as I told because I have too many schema)

***I want to ask you:***

Is this possible for meteor to use something like below autoform, and use just one autoform (form generator) for all schema?

```
{{> quickForm collection="Ads" schema="AdsBaseSchema" id="insertAds" type="insert"}}
```

***Is it possible using both of "collection" and "schema" attribute in autoform??***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solutio for this issue:

I could try writing a helper for my template which returns a schema name dynamically, like so:

```
{{> quickForm collection="Ads" schema=schema id="insertAds" type="insert"}}
```

helper:

```
Template['myTemplate'].helpers({
 schema() {
 //Write your logic here
 return "adsBaseSchema";
 }
})
```

and fortunately it worked.

Comment: You found or got the answer here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/1389 It's always good to give the idea author's credits...